# MathJax not rendering in previews

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview

As of today, when I type an answer, things in MathJax don't get rendered in the preview.  What's going on?[image]

Comment: Tried hard refresh (or testing via private mode browsing)? Multiple browsers/operating systems?

Comment: [same question, in very recent times](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22551/problems-with-losing-mathjax-formatting-previews-while-creating-question-or-answ).

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  I may post some updates here shortly.

Comment: I've had this problem intermittently in the last week.  My first thought was it related to having [switched up the Math Renderer choice](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22539/line-breaking-in-mathjax-common-html).  It seems more prone to failure while editing an existing Answer, but I have had the problem with first drafting of an Answer.  Switching back to Common-HTML for rendering doesn't seem to have entirely solved my difficulties.  This sometimes has been attributed to network failure to connect to the MathJax server.

Comment: I had problems with MathJax not rendering at random times. Tried a different browser, no problem since then. (Chromium works for me. I know this is probably not the "right" answer, but it solved the problem...)

Comment: It's happened to me before, too. Disabling Flash player might help, I don't know why, though.

Comment: Users are [reporting similar problems](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/mathjax-not-rendering) on DSP.SE.

Comment: When I was typing [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664347/uniqueness-of-memoryless-property/1664424#1664424), I saw the preview as I was typing, until I didn't see it and it just showed unrendered code. It changed from one to the other in the course of one answer.

Comment: This is the same issue as reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275997/mathjax-preview-bug-seems-to-be-neglected), where there are instructions for reproducing the issue.  I'm looking into it, and should be able to resolve it.

Comment: Could you maybe trim the screen-shot to the essential.

Comment: See my [post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/mathjax-editing-preview-improvements-userscript) that includes a user-script to work around the problem until the editing code is updated.